# loading a page in visualforce using jquery

Tags: jquery, apex-code, visualforce

I'm trying to embed a website in my visualforce page, but the code isn't working.

```
<apex:page >
   <apex:includeScript value="{$Resource.jQuery}"  />
   <script>
      $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      function LoadPage(){
      $.get('http://google.com, function(data) {
      $('#siteloader').html(data);
  });
}
   </script>

<body>
onload=LoadPage();
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You missed an `'` after google.com, however it will still not work. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Yea, this is limited by XSS, cannot be done. You can use a server side component to pull the contents of said external page and feed those too you. In php you can use `echo file_get_contents($url)` and return the markup to the AJAX call.

Comment: can you  point me to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use AJAX to display the site? 
Did you tried an [iframe tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)?